# Could anyone clarify why this Boolean expression AB'+AB'AC' = AB'?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could anyone clarify why this Boolean expression AB'+AB'AC' = AB'? I did not understand what happened to the C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $AB'$ is true, the $+$ will not change that.

If $AB'$ is false, then $(AB')(AC')$ is also false, no matter what $C'$ is. Then the entire expression is false, which is equal to $AB'$

Comment: Thank's Andrei!!!!

Comment: No Problem. If you find the answer useful, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

$$AB'+AB'AC'=AB'(1+AC')=AB'1=AB'$$